# Use Count to count the number of characters in two separate strings

Tags: python, count

I am trying to use count to count the number of characters in two separate strings. I can get it to work for just one but how can I format it to count for two strings? I have tried using 'and' but it is not working. What I want is when the user enters inputs for name1(Anna) and name2(Andy) I want the result to be 3 counting the letter 'a' in both names.

```
name1 = input("What is your name? \n")
name2 = input("What is their name? \n")
lower1 = name1.lower()
lower2 = name2.lower()
a = lower1.count("a") and lower2.count("a")
print(a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`and` is [boolean operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

> The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is
> returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
> returned.

You want to use addition

```
a = lower1.count("a") + lower2.count("a")
```

Comment: Ah of course that makes sense now! Thanks so much.... looking back on it now its so clear! If those were just numbers I would never use "and" to add numbers (eg 3 "and" 6 as opposed to 3 "+" 6)! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can also first concatenate the two strings and then count:

```
a = (lower1 + lower2).count("a")
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to add the two counts, right? So simply:

```py
a = lower1.count("a") + lower2.count("a")
print(a)
```

should be enough in your case.

Answer (score 0):

**and** is a boolean operator, which cant be used when assigning variables with the sum of two other variables. The correct way is:

```
a = lower1.count("a") + lower2.count("a")
```